# What is the standard environment variable used to specify a temporary directory?

Tags: environment-variables, temporary-directory

I am writing a [script](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/intemp) that uses a temporary directory, and I would like to allow it to read the user's chosen temporary directory from an environment variable. What environment variable(s) should my script look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows: %TEMP%, or %TMP%
Linux: $TMP, $TEMP

Those are the most common